# How to link to images in my plugin regardless of the plugin folder's name

Tags: plugin-development

What is the correct method to refer to images from within your plugin code, so that no matter what the folder is named, they resolve correctly?

I had an issue where a user downloaded my plugin twice, then used the 2nd downloaded file to install it. Since Windows automatically named duplicate files foldername(2).zip, when my plugin was uploaded to the site, it was placed in a folder named "foldername(2). So since my images were linked to wp-content/plugins/foldername/img/foo.png, none of the images were showing up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure about this specific example but in general [`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) is fitting function for this.

Example from Codex:

```
plugins_url('/images/wordpress.png', __FILE__);
```

Answer (score 6):

As has already been said, use `plugins_url($path, $plugin_file)`.

You should **always** avoid hard-coding paths as much as possible, since not only can a user rename a plugin folder, they can [move the entire `wp-content` directory](http://wpshout.com/move-your-wp-content-area/)!

Here's a few functions and constants I always use;

- `WP_CONTENT_DIR`
  Absolute filepath to `wp-content` directory
- `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`
  Absolute filepath to `wp-content/plugins` directory
- `wp_upload_dir($time)`
  Get filesystem and URL paths to uploads directory, optionally for a
  specific time (if using year/month
  folders)
- `site_url($path)`
  Absolute URL to WordPress install
- `home_url($path)`
  Absolute URL to WordPress home (front page per se)
- `plugins_url($path, $file)`
  Uses `plugin_basename($file)` to get the absolute URL for the
  directory that `$file` currently
  resides in, and appends `$path`
- `plugin_basename($file)`
  Get the *relative* path from the plugins folder to `$file`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_basename

From the example:

> If your plugin file is located at /home/www/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php, and you call:
>
> ```
> $x = plugin_basename(__FILE__);
> ```
>
> $x will equal "myplugin/myplugin.php".
>
> If you would like to know the full url path to your plugin's directory, you can call:
>
> ```
> $x = WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'.str_replace(basename( __FILE__),"",plugin_basename(__FILE__));
> ```
>
> $x will equal "http://[url-path-to-plugins]/[myplugin]/"

Answer (score 0):

I think using [plugin_dir_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) solves this efficiently:

```
$url = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);

$imageurl = $url.'images/wordpress.png'l
```