# Plugin base URL

Tags: plugin-development, paths

In a question that is related to, but not the same as, [How to link to images in my plugin regardless of the plugin folder's name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5144/how-to-link-to-images-in-my-plugin-regardless-of-the-plugin-folders-name/)

- `plugin-folder/plugin-main-file.php`
- `plugin-folder/images/` containing all images
- `plugin-folder/classes/` containing class definitions
- `plugin-folder/classes/class1-files` containing additional files for class 1
- `plugin-folder/classes/class2-files` containing additional files for class 2
- etc

To access images, I can use relative addressing, such as `plugins_url( '../images/image.png', dirname( __FILE__ ) )` but this requires a knowledge of the file structure, and a level of hard-coding that leads to potential maintenance issues.

Alternatively, I can define a global constant (eg) `define('PLUGIN_ROOT', basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/' . basename(__FILE__));` in my main-file.

Ideally, there is a Wordpress function that would give me the plugin base name, from anywhere in my plugin (ie always return `/plugin-folder/`)... but I haven't found one.  Is there such a beastie?

-- EDIT TO ADD --

I am also aware of `plugins_url()` with no parameters... but this returns `http://mydomain.ext/wp-content/plugins` - ie without my plugin name!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [plugin_dir_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url):

```
$url = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);

$imageurl = $url.'images/someimage.png';
```

**EDIT**: Sorry I misread the question... that is only an answer to the linked question. You could check the parent directory recursively until you find the right one:

```
function base_plugin_dir($dirpath) {
    if (substr(dirname($dir),-7) == 'plugins') {return $dirpath;}
    else {$dirpath = base_plugin_dir($dirpath);}
    return $dirpath;
}

function base_plugin_dir_url($filepath) {
    $baseplugindir = base_plugin_dir(dirname($filepath));
    $url = plugin_dir_url(trailingslashit($baseplugindir));
    return $url;
}
```

Then you can get the URL using that function from whatever file:

```
$basepluginurl = base_plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);
$imageurl = $basepluginurl.'/images/wordpress.png';
```

**OR**

Better yet just set a constant from your main plugin file to use it later:

```
$url = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);
define('MY_UNIQUE_PLUGIN_URL',$url);
```

So as to use in say `/plugin/my-plugin/class/class1.php`

```
$imageurl = MY_UNIQUE_PLUGIN_URL.'/images/wordpress.png';
```

Comment: It seems DEFINE is the way-ahead... maybe this is a feature that needs adding, as I can't (surely) be the only one who wants this!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer, below is the function I use to retrieve the plugin directory name in the format requested by @Andrew (i.e. with a trailing slash as mentioned in the comment to Kevin)

```
/**
 * Retrieve the Plugin Directory 
 * 
 * Returns the root directory for current plugin with a trailing slash
 */
function current_plugin_dir() {
  $base = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
  $slash = strpos($base,'/');
  $plugin_dir = $loc? substr( $base, 0, $loc + 1): $base;
  return $plugin_dir;
}
```

To remove the slash just leave out the '+ 1' in the $plugin_dir line.

Comment: Thanks. A late answer is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

My bad, in that case I can think of this.

```
$x = WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'.str_replace(basename( __FILE__),"",plugin_basename(__FILE__));
```

It should return

http://[url-path-to-plugins]/[custom-plugin]/

But straight forward class I don't think wordpress has one

---

Yes it is

from https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_basename

```
$x = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
```

Comment: Thanks... I am aware of basename - but for file `plugin-folder/classes/class1-files/class1-file1.php` that returns `plugin-folder/classes/class1-files/class1-file1.php` not the desired `plugin-folder/` URL

Answer (score 0):

`plugin_basename` may be what you want. If your plugin file is located at `/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.php` this would return:

```
$file = plugin_basename( __FILE__ ); // "my-plugin/my-plugin.php"
```

If you called the same thing from a sub-directory in your plugin, such as `/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/inc/my-plugin-include.php` it would return:

```
my-plugin/inc/my-plugin-include.php
```

If you want the current root directory for a plugin, then this custom function should do the trick:

```
/**
 * Current Plugin Directory 
 * 
 * Returns the root directory for current plugin
 */
function current_plugin_dir() {
    $basename = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );

    return str_replace( __FILE__, '', $basename );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin... I am wanting `my-plugin/`

Comment: Got it. I just added a function for this to the bottom of my response. I think this should cover it for you Andrew, but let me know how it works out.