# Plugin path comes wrongly

Tags: plugin-development, directory, paths

I need import css files from a folder in plugin directory to a plugin php file.

I tried

```
plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo __DIR__ . '/dahili/bootstrap.min.css'; ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dahili/bootstrap.min.css">
```

but they gives wrong url.

for example, in my last trying, I get this adress:

http://www.hekim.deniz-tasarim.site/home/deniztas/hekim.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/plugins/my_post_plugin/widgets/dahili/bootstrap.min.css

but I need this:

hekim.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/plugins/my_post_plugin/widgets/dahili/bootstrap.min.css

how to get true address?

> Note: Please dont close my question because of dublicate if you dont
>   give 100% same question because I need real solution, I am not troll.

Comment: Are you noting the difference between a file system "path" and URL?

Comment: @jdm2112 In fact, I didnt understood your comment.Can you please explain?

Comment: You're calling [plugin_dir_path](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/), which gets the filesystem path (starting with /home/). You want [plugin_dir_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_url/), which gets the base URL. Or other options on this question: [How to link to images in my plugin regardless of the plugin folder's name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/5144/3276)

Comment: @Rup thanks, it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, we must use `plugin_dir_url` command.

For example:

```
<?php
                    wp_register_style( 'foo-styles',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'dahili/bootstrap.min.css' );
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'foo-styles' );

?>
```